# Callback by finishing the animation in JS

Tags: javascript, animation

I have written the function that generates the frames for animation in JS, and I want to use chaining way to call callback function by finishing the animation. For this purpose I wrote the following code:

```
var _proto = Array.prototype;

var Animation = function( duration, callback ) {
 var begin = new Date(), delta, then = []
  , cid = setInterval(function(){
      delta = (new Date() - begin) / duration;
      delta > 1 && ( delta = 1 )
       callback( delta )
        if( delta === 1 ) { 
         clearInterval( cid );
          if( then.length ) {
           var i = 0;
             for( ; i < then.length; i++ ) {
              then[i].call( this )
            }
          }
        }
      }, 10 );
   return { 
     then : function(){
      _proto.push.apply( then , _proto.slice.call( arguments ) );
      return this;
    } 
  }
};
```

and use it this way:

```
Animation( 450 , function( delta ){
 // frames
}).then(function(){
   // after finish 
})
```

is it good way to create "then" method in this case? or you can give any advice.

Comment: This doesn't support some features that are common in promises libraries: If you call then after the animation has finished running the callback will not be called, your then does not receive an error callback, etc. If I were you I would keep it simple and code the animation with raw callbacks. If you want `then`, you can use one of the many promises libraries out there - they all provide a way to convert callback code into promise objects.

Comment: I suppose the name of method tells that I am about to realize deferred object. It is not. This is just a method that must be called after finishing the animation by using chaining way. It is something like success in old version jQuery.

Comment: This is a big matter of taste but I'm not a big fan of using chaining just for the syntax, like you are doing. I would prefer to keep it simple and just pass the callback as a regular argument. I would only code it using a separate then method if I wanted to be able to add callbacks even after the animation is finished (this is impossible to do if you har to pass the callbacks as a parameter at the start).

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=promises) you can create promises without any library at all. Your code should look like this:

```
var Animation = function( duration, callback ) {
    return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject) {
        // Your code ...
        setInterval(function(){
            // More of your code ...
            if (something) {
                // When it's done ...
                fulfill()
            }
        }, 10)
    })
}
```

The promise object returned should have a `then` method.